# JavaFX canvas redraw doesn't do anything

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, redraw

I have a Canvas on which I'm drawing an Airplane , on a speficiec location(The first drawing works well) . While my program runs, I need to sample the airplane location from another server and update my plane location accordingly.

Everything works fine(parameters wise) , except nothing is being redrawned..

**EDIT:** Correction - a little smudge is being drawned on top of the original airplane, and then nothing else happens

My code:

```
public class AirplaneDrawer extends Canvas{
    double x,y,rotate;

    public void setCords(double x,double y,double rotate) {
        if(x != this.x || y != this.y || rotate != this.rotate) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.rotate = rotate;
            redraw();
        }
    }

    public void redraw() {
        GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
        String path = new String("M 323.193 226.645 c 39.244 24.41 75.644 47.053 115.706 71.978 c 7.687 -5.443 20.518 -14.485 33.308 -23.596 c 16.733 -11.923 36.27 -11.452 49.046 3.779 c 3.513 4.191 2.568 15.766 -0.705 21.426 c -23.705 40.994 -48.427 81.404 -73.095 121.833 c -4.729 7.745 -9.06 19.278 -21.177 13.509 c -12.203 -5.8 -28.746 -9.521 -27.842 -28.026 c 0.891 -18.185 3.495 -36.292 4.924 -50.249 c -40.704 -19.793 -79.74 -38.778 -119.825 -58.269 c -16.168 17.561 -22.275 40.532 -27.606 64.119 c -8.975 39.719 -18.474 79.324 -28.171 118.881 c -5.593 22.809 -12.452 26.109 -34.167 17.908 c -28.122 -10.606 -31.047 -14.689 -31.318 -45.384 c -0.605 -68.198 -1.514 -136.4 -1.325 -204.593 c 0.045 -15.865 -4.177 -25.531 -19.237 -32.95 c -30.238 -14.884 -60.119 -30.866 -88.548 -48.915 c -13.988 -8.884 -26.951 -21.77 -35.867 -35.727 C 3.526 110.834 15.381 90.43 40.637 91.746 c 17.786 0.931 36.644 4.67 52.618 12.229 c 32.58 15.413 63.735 33.905 95.022 51.921 c 8.735 5.028 15.083 4.992 23.944 0.068 c 64.671 -35.921 129.717 -71.172 194.611 -106.705 c 25.712 -14.075 46.608 -10.335 65.331 12.008 c 10.309 12.302 2.247 20.797 -6.506 28.579 c -35.89 31.91 -72.438 63.093 -107.682 95.687 C 344.877 197.641 334.677 212.878 323.193 226.645 Z");
        double wid = getWidth()/247;
        double hei = getHeight()/152;
        gc.translate(wid*x,hei*y);
        gc.scale(0.02,0.02);    
        gc.rotate(rotate);
        gc.appendSVGPath(path);
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fill();
        gc.stroke();
    }
```

}

I thought maybe the GraphicContext remebers the last scale/translate/rotatation , so I've tried adding a second `if` at the beggining of the `if` in `setCords` method, that if its not the first drawing, undo those steps backwards, but it didn't change anything.

**EDIT:** If I use this condition, then the smudge that I mentioned earlier in the first edit doesn't appear and nothing is being redrawned

```
        if(this.x!=0 || this.y!= 0 || this.rotate != 0) {
            GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
            double wid = getWidth()/247;
            double hei = getHeight()/152;
            gc.rotate(-this.rotate);
            gc.scale(50, 50);
            gc.translate(-wid*this.x,-hei*this.y);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? (I've debugged and saw the `setCords` are being invoked with correct parameters as needed)

**Note:** I dont know if it matter, but the call to `setCords` is being made in a separete Thread, so my program will continue as usual .

Thanks!

Comment: _Unrelated:_ Don't use `new String(...)`, just use the string literal. In other words, use `String path = "...";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention:

> **Note:** I dont know if it matter, but the call to `setCords` is being made in a separete Thread, so my program will continue as usual .

This does matter. From the documentation of [`GraphicsContext`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html):

> A `Canvas` only contains one `GraphicsContext`, and only one buffer. If it is not attached to any scene, then it can be modified by any thread, as long as it is only used from one thread at a time. Once a `Canvas` node is attached to a scene, it must be modified on the JavaFX Application Thread.
>
> Calling any method on the `GraphicsContext` is considered modifying its corresponding `Canvas` and is subject to the same threading rules.

If you're on a background thread you can publish an action to the FX thread using [`Platform.runLater(Runnable)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)). Take care not to flood the FX thread with too many actions, however. You may want to consider using an [`AnimationTimer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) instead of, or possibly in conjunction with (using proper synchronization), a separate thread.

Also, be aware that drawing on a `Canvas` does not clear anything previously drawn. To simulate movement you need to clear the appropriate area (or draw over it, e.g. with the background) and then redraw it in a different position. This can be as specific as only clearing/drawing over what's changed or as general as redrawing the entire canvas every time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I used the `runLater` through my second thread to call `setCords` , but it doesn't seems to change anything.. Still the parameters sent to the method are right, but nothing new is being drawn to the canvas.. I also added `gc.clearRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight())` to the code , but it doesn't clear anything (or maybe it does but just redraw it in the same position)

Comment: Try to create a [mre] demonstrating the issue (as opposed to the snippets you currently have) and then edit your question. We need to see how everything fits together.  _**Note:** Don't just dump your entire project into the question. Try to create the example from scratch with just enough code to demonstrate the issue. The "[mre]" link provides some useful tips._

Comment: Sorry for not giving all the required details, it just seemed unrellevant. I'll approve this though I was wrong on the source of the problem, so I opened a new question haha, you're more than welcome to look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674201/javafx-canvas-redraw-always-in-the-same-location